# Converting centimeter to mile with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Basic programming language. I have a unit converter that is currently converting lengths. My issue is when I convert 1 centimeter to mile I get 6.214E-06. Now, I understand this to be 6.214 x 10^-6, but I want it to display the actual number and not scientific notation. I believe it would be much easier on the user. How do I make it display the actual number (0.000006214)?

```
            ' converts centimeter to...
            If cbo1.SelectedItem = "Centimeter" Then
                If cbo2.SelectedItem = "Kilometer" Then
                    txtUnit2.Text = Math.Round(dblUnit1 * 0.0001, 6).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Meter" Then
                    txtUnit2.Text = Math.Round(dblUnit1 * 0.01, 6).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Centimeter" Then
                    txtUnit2.Text = txtUnit1.Text
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Millimeter" Then
                    txtUnit2.Text = Math.Round(dblUnit1 * 10, 6).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Mile" Then
                    txtUnit2.Text = dblUnit1 * 0.000006214.ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Yard" Then
                    txtUnit2.Text = Math.Round(dblUnit1 * 0.010936133, 6).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Foot" Then
                    txtUnit2.Text = Math.Round(dblUnit1 * 0.032808399, 6).ToString.Trim
                ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Inch" Then
                    txtUnit2.Text = Math.Round(dblUnit1 * 0.393700787, 6).ToString.Trim
                End If
            End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the data type from Double to Decimal has solved the issue! I wrestled with all these formatting methods only to find more restriction or unwanted behavior. Thanks to all for their input. My updated code is below.

```
Private Function GetLength1(ByVal decLengthUnit1 As Decimal) As Decimal

    Dim decResult1 As Decimal

    If cboUnitType.SelectedItem = "Length" Then

        ' converts centimeter to...
        If cbo1.SelectedItem = "Centimeter" Then
            If cbo2.SelectedItem = "Kilometer" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 0.0001)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Meter" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 0.01)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Centimeter" Then
                decResult1 = txtUnit1.Text
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Millimeter" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 10)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Mile" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 0.000006214)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Yard" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 0.010936133)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Foot" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 0.032808399)
            ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Inch" Then
                decResult1 = (decLengthUnit1 * 0.393700787)
            End If
        End If

    Return decResult1
End Function


Private Sub txtUnit1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtUnit1.TextChanged

    If suppressTextBox1TextChanged = False Then

        Decimal.TryParse(txtUnit1.Text, decUnit1)

        ' if String.Empty
        If txtUnit1.Text = "" Then
            txtUnit2.Text = ""
        Else
            ' trigger the function
            suppressTextBox2TextChanged = True
            txtUnit2.Text = GetLength1(decUnit1)
            suppressTextBox2TextChanged = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

What you need is to use the "N" format:

```
output = value.ToString("N")
```

this should output the number as

> 0.000006214

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `value.ToString("R")`
see here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I get `6.214E-06` using `value.ToString("R")` in VS2013.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `value.ToString("N99").TrimEnd("0"c)` (99 is the largest number of digits the format specifier will work with).

Or you could take the digits of the number and prepend them with the appropriate number of zeros, which will work for numbers smaller than 1E-99, although I don't think that would be easier on the user's eyes:

```
Module Module1

    Function DoubleToString(x As Double) As String
        Dim sf As String = x.ToString()
        ' If the number would not be displayed in scientific format, there is no
        ' need to process it.
        Dim eLocation As Integer = sf.IndexOf({"E"c}, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        If eLocation = -1 Then
            Return sf
        End If

        Dim decSeparator As Char = CChar(Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)

        Dim magnitude As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(x))))

        If magnitude < 0 Then
            Dim digits As String = (x * 10 ^ (-magnitude)).ToString().Replace(decSeparator, "")
            Dim sign As String = ""
            If x < 0 Then
                sign = "-"
                digits = digits.Substring(1)
            End If
            Return String.Format("{0}0{1}{2}{3}", sign, decSeparator, New String("0"c, -magnitude - 1), digits)
        Else
            ' Could process it to display large numbers.
            Return sf
        End If

    End Function
    Sub Main()
        Dim value As Double = 0.00006214
        ' A simple way.
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N99").TrimEnd("0"c))

        Console.WriteLine(DoubleToString(value))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

And `DoubleToString(1.23456789E-190)` gives `0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000123456789`.